# Angular post returns 403 while get returns 301 in Django using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, angularjs, django, post, django-rest-framework

Here is my angular service

```
function register(email, password, confirm_password, username){
  // get works
  // $http.get('/api/v1/accounts/'); 

  return $http.post('/api/v1/accounts/',{
    username: username,
    password: password,
    email: email
  });
}
```

Here is my `create` function for my viewset

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'Post':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

    def create(self, request):
        print "this is not printing at all"
```

Here is my `urls`

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),

]
```

I config my angular app with csrf using this

```
angular
.module('main')
.run(run);

run.$inject = ['$http'];

function run($http) {
  console.log("I double check this runs");
  $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
  $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}
```

However whenever I try to `post` using `$http` I get

```
403 (FORBIDDEN)
```

While I was able to use `get`

Did I miss something?

Edit:

I think get_permissions is not working as intended

If I set the permission in global

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

the code works, however, if I use `get_permissions` , the code doesn't work, this is surprising as I trace through the [git repo](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L222) and it seems like `get_permissions` always gets called when checking permissions

Comment: Look into this tutorial. He has a great example http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html

Comment: Actually, as Glyn pointed out, the issue is indeed in the permission setting, in `get_permissions` I checked for `=="Post"` instead of `=="POST"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple authentication or authorization (permissions) issue. I don't see any authentication permissions in your view so I assume DRF is using defaults. Anonymous users are not allowed to post by default `(I don't think, anyway)` django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions